# drupal confirm_password field set description under both textboxes in drupal

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

i have an confirm password field in the drupal and i need to set description for both the text boxes and i tried this.

```
$form['pass[pass1]']['#description'] = 'textbox1';
$form['pass[pass2]']['#description'] = 'textbox2';
```

is that possible . can any one please explain how to do it .

i tried this too.

```
   $form['pass']['pass1']['#description'] = 'textbox1';
    $form['pass']['pass2']['#description'] = 'textbox2';
```

for both code nothing changes in the gui

Answer (score 0):

The password field gets split into two in the [expand_password_confirm](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes--form.inc/function/expand_password_confirm/6) function (called pass1 and pass2 like you've got above so I guess you probably already know that). You can probably change the descriptions in a form pre render function, so in your form put:

```
$form['#pre_render'] = array('MYMODULE_my_form_pre_render');
```

And then create the following function:

```
function MYMODULE_my_form_pre_render(&$form) {
  $form['pass']['pass1']['#description'] = 'textbox1';
  $form['pass']['pass2']['#description'] = 'textbox2';
}
```

Hope that helps